# how to update a view when a change happened in other view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 dashboards one for the user (printshop )and the other for the admin (QA ) and I want the user dashboard to be updated automatically when the admin changes the status of the order in the admin dashboard without having to refresh the page every time a change happens.

here's
 myService.js in QA dashboard

```
function addOrederToPrintShop(printShopId, orderId, index, key) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    service.db.collection('orders').doc(orderId).set({
        printShopStatus: 'Pending'
    }, {
        merge: true
    }).then(function(data) {
        service.db.collection('print-shops- 
            orders ').doc(printShopId).collection(orderId).doc(key).get()
            .then(function(doc) {
                    if (!doc.exists) {
                        ////if print shop not added
                        service.db.collection('print-shops- 
                            orders ').doc(printShopId).collection(orderId).doc(key).set({key: 
                            key
                        })
                    .then(function() {
                            addOredersToPrintShopArray(printShopId, orderId);
                            service.db.collection('orders').doc(orderId).get()
                                .then(function(order) {
                                    if (order.exists) {
                                        var fetchedOrder = order.data();

                                        fetchedOrder.cart[index].printShopStatus = 'Pending';


                                        service.db.collection('orders').doc(orderId).set({
                                            cart: fetchedOrder.cart
                                        }, {
                                            merge: true
                                        }).then(function() {
                                            resolve('Document successfully added!');
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            reject("Error added document: ", error);
                        });
                } else {
                    resolve('Document NOT!');
                }
            });
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Might be `SubjectBehavior` do a work for you but I m not sure about angularJS

Comment: You need something like websockets, or a continual AJAX request system, that will update the data when it gets updated on the server side.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about two separate client instances running on different machines, right, an admin client and a separate user client?

Comment: yes, but they are connected like when a status change by the admin it will change in the user dashboard and vice versa my only problem is I want the updated changes to show up without having to refresh the page

Comment: guys, I've posted a piece of my code in my question to be more clear for you, please check it out, thanks.

Comment: Use Websockets to do it. Inform server when one value changes and then inform other from server side using websockets.

Comment: The use of `Promise(resolve,reject)`to resolve from inside a promise handler is considered an anti-pattern. There is at least one condition where the `new Promise` will hang because of a lack a `resolve` or `reject`. With the nesting, lack of indentation, and the errors, it is hard to tell the intention of the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the lack of indentation and code errors makes it unclear what you are asking.

Comment: well thanks for your vote it's very helpful